# How to set the default width of fill mode to 80 with emacs?

Tags: emacs

I know that "C-u 80 C-x f" sets the fill width 80, and M-q adjusts it.
How to make it default? I mean, how to make width 80 deafault for fill width?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In your .emacs place `(setq-default fill-column 80)` Or you can just use M-x customize-variable on fill-column, and it will set it and save it for you using the standard customize interface.

Comment: AFAIU `fill-column` is a buffer-local variable, which is why you need [`setq-default`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18173666/52499), not just `setq`.