# The difference between setq and setq-default in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a question about Emacs Lisp. What is the difference between **setq** and **setq-default**?

Tutorials say **setq** takes effect in the *local buffer* while **setq-default** affects all buffers.

For example, if I wrote **(setq a-var a-vars-value)** in **init.el**, I found after starting Emacs and opening a new buffer, the **a-var** is also there and its value is **a-vars-value**. I thought it was not supposed to be there. It seems there is no difference between **setq** and **setq-default**.

Is there something wrong with my understanding?

For example:

1. I wrote **(setq hello 123)** in the **init.el** file, and I run **emacs abuffer** in the shell, then I input **"hello C-x C-e"**, it shows "123". The same happens when I run this in all new buffers.
2. I wrote **(setq tab-width 4)** in the **init.el** file. When I run **tab-width C-x C-e**, it shows "8" (Current mode is 'Text'). However, when I use **(setq-default tab-width 4)**, it show "4". I can't explain this phenomenon.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Some variables in Emacs are "buffer-local", meaning that each buffer is allowed to have a separate value for that variable that overrides the global default. `tab-width` is a good example of a buffer-local variable.

If a variable is buffer-local, then `setq` sets its local value in the current buffer and `setq-default` sets the global default value.

If a variable is not buffer-local, then `setq` and `setq-default` do the same thing.

In your case 2, `(setq tab-width 4)` set the buffer-local value of `tab-width` to 4 in the current buffer, leaving the global default value of `tab-width` still at 8, so when you evaluated `tab-width` in a different buffer that had no local value, you saw that 8. Then, when you set the default value to 4, that buffer picked it up, since it still had no local value.

Comment: when I (sets tab-width 4), and evaluate it, it is always 8 in every buffer. I don't know why. Seems it does not take effect. But when I use (sets-default tab-width 4), it takes effect in every buffer. I also do not know why:(

Comment: `(setq tab-width 4)` takes effect in the buffer where you evaluated the expression; if you evaluate it in the `*scratch*` buffer then examine its value in that buffer.

Comment: `tab-width` is a buffer-local variable. So when you `(setq tab-width 4)`, it is only set to 4 in the current buffer. All other buffers retain a `tab-width` of the global default, 8. When you `(setq-default tab-width 4)`, you are changing the global default of `tab-width` to 4, so now every buffer that has not defined `tab-width` itself has that new default.

Comment: I add (setq tab-width 4) in init.el, and I run "emacs hello" to open buffer hello. Is there possibility that the sentence in init.el does not take effect on buffer 'hello' in this way?

Comment: Yes. See the list of emacs' [Sequence of Actions at Startup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html). Reading the init file is step 12, and bringing up the initial buffer is step 23.

Comment: ah, enlightened. So when i (setq tab-width 4), no buffer is initialized and there is no specific buffer that corresponds to '(setq tab-width 4)'. In this case, this config in 'init.el' is somewhat useless, am i right?

Comment: @ruanhao If you (setq tab-width 4) in the init.el, then it will only apply to that buffer (init.el). If you want this change to apply to all new buffers, then (setq-default tab-width 4) will accomplish this. Additionally, if you want to create a mode for a specific type of file, you would probably want to use (setq tab-width 4) so as not to override the global default.

Comment: How can you tell if a variable is buffer-local or not?

Comment: The easiest way as a user is to type `C-h v tab-width` (say) and look at the documentation for it.